# Execute a binary file in ruby (on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, executable, heroku

Is it possible to execute a little binary file (required for payment processing) with Kernel#exec from a ruby app hosted on Heroku ? Or do I need to switch to another rails hosting solution ?

Comment: It would be faster to write a test case and figure it out yourself.

Comment: Suppose it could work, just try it... And post the answer of course for future reference!

Comment: things like exec('ruby -v') or exec('ls') work but when I'm trying exec(File.dirname(__FILE__))+'/myexec') I'm getting a 'permissin denied' error, is there something wrong here ? or maybe it's just the way Heroku's architecture work ?

Answer (score 4):

Heroku does allow for the compilation of native gems from it's [gem manifests](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/10/gem_manifests/) so there is a distinct possibility that you will be able to package the binary up as a gem and get heroku to run it as such. Make sure you set the binary to be executable before you push it to heroku as git is permissions aware.

Comment: I've thought about that too, but Heroku support answered the question yesterday: only executables in the "/bin" subdirectory of the app can be executed